# Algebraic manipulation: what is the best tool?

Tags: proof-assistant, proof-search, computer-algebra-system

I have a set of algebraic axioms. I need to prove an equation, an algebraic law. What I did was applying "trivial" rewrite rules by a theorem prover from both ends, and then an automatic theorem prover has found *some* proof whose structure I do not know.

I would like to find a series of steps in equational reasoning where I see the rule used for every step.

My algebraic theory is formulated in basic category theory.

What is the best tool for this out there? Some computer algebra software?

Comment: Would [Prover9](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/prover9/) fit the bill? (At the moment the link is not working for me, there's also [GitHub repo](https://github.com/ai4reason/Prover9)).

Comment: Andrej's link seems to be working now.  Depending on the quantification in axioms, equational algebraic theories (like group theory) are called [varieties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_(universal_algebra)), but this is a fairly limited subset.

Comment: @AndrejBauer it seems that Prover9 is based on first order logic, which might not be expressive enough for my problem.

Comment: Perhaps you're using the phrase "algebraic theory" in some non-standard way? An algebraic theory has only equations, so not even first-order logic (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebraic+theory).

Comment: @AndrejBauer I formulated this in higher order logic, where identity has different types, depending on where it appears. That is why I asked for higher types.

Comment: You have not showed us anything, it is impossible to tell what you are doing.